# Why is there a mistake in class specialization?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to implement the dictionaries in C ++, but when I define the specialization of the class hash I get the error:

```
error: 'hash' is not a class template
error: template argument required for 'class hash'
```

Here is the code

```
template <class T>
class hash{
public:
  size_t operator()(const T the_key) const;
};


/* a specialization with type string */
template<>
class hash<string>
{
public:
  size_t operator()(const string the_key) const {
    unsigned long hash_value = 0;
    int length = (int) the_key.length();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
      hash_value = 5 * hash_value + the_key.at(i);
    return size_t(hash_value);
  }
};
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The code shown doesn't have an obvious cause for the error message you report. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/sdU2k3) which compiles fine. The problem is likely in how or where you use `hash`.

Comment: Notes : `const string the_key` should be `const string & the_key` to avoid making needless copies and you could probably just use `size_t` for `hash_value`, `length` and `i` to avoid any kind of cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, except that you probably had `using namespace std` in your code, which causes your `hash` template to conflict with the std one. Remove that, and the problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem! Why does it conflict if I use the namespace std?

Comment: @Tony9999 `using namespace std` tells the compiler to look up unqualified names in namespace `std`. So, when you later reference `hash`, both your own `::hash` and `std::hash` are found.

Comment: Perfect, I understand. I had no idea std::hash also existed

Comment: One of the many reasons [`using namespace std` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10957435).

Comment: @Tony9999 little shame in that--there are few people who know everything lurking in `std`--but this is one of the primary reasons not to `using namespace std;` The other big reason is stuff gets added so what works today could be a mystery bug  tomorrow.